# php swoole with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, asynchronous, swoole

i want to use swoole for a new project. Is there a way to use swoole with MSSQL? I read in the docs that they have coroutines for MySql, Postgres, Redis. But I didn't find anything about MSSQL.

Comment: You can use co-routines anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So inside go functions you can connect to mssql and make your query and this query will be executed asynchronous? So why they have prebuild connectors for MySql? Is there any difference?

Comment: Better use transactions when you need transaction safeness. It is prebuild for convenience and performance. MySQL is just THE optimal DB for PHP since ages.

Comment: So you think swoole will have better performance with MySQL instead of MSSQL?

Comment: Special DB have special purposes. But I ever would prefer mySQL.